# How to run a class method after its constructor (Qt GUI)?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

A QMainwindow object is constructed and show()n in the program's main() function.
This object's constructur is used to create all GUI widgets.
It contains additional code (or a method call) that is currently run before the QMainWindow widget is visible.

This code / method should be run once after the QMainWindow constructor, i.e. when the application window is visible.

According the the documentation of [showEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showEvent), it may be run more than once.

Do I need to use some sort of toggle flag inside this event, or is there a "better" solution (I thought I read that a QTimer could be used to enqueue methods to the event loop)?

Comment: @vahancho He wants to run the code after the mainwindow is shown, ie queued function call.

Comment: "_...after the QMainWindow constructor, i.e. when the application window is visible_". Those are two different things. Which is it?

Comment: @DDrmmr The application window is only visible after the constructor has finished and the show() method is called, so it may be redundant, but it's only one "thing" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using a Qt singleshot timer with timeout of 0 seconds. Call this at the end of your mainwindow constructor connecting your callback function as the slot:

```
QTimer::singleShot( 0, this, SLOT( onLoad() ) );
```

Comment: Imo `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with `Qt::QueuedConnection` looks more readable, that timer.